# how to formate date in input type=text in reactive form in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

i want dd/MM/yyyy format in input field with type = text,
how i can achieve that please help, i want add a / after dd(01) mm(01) yyyy,
can you suggest me any pipe for this format or adding / in this

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried so we are able to help.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to have a mask in your input field.

Maybe some librairies like [angular-imask](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/master/packages/angular-imask) can provide the functionnalities you need.

And some [documentation](https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-date) about the use of date mask.